# Any successful examples of funding research through crowd funding?

Tags: funding

Has there been any successful examples of crowd funded academic research projects? (i.e., instead of grants from funding agencies)

I would restrict the scope of this question to only within academia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tabby's star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabby%27s_Star) is a variable star that used [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/608159144/the-most-mysterious-star-in-the-galaxy/description) to crowdfund the purchase of telescope time on Las Cumbres Observatory. The observations and many others concluded the mysterious variability was caused by dust extinction around the star.

Answer (score 1):

[crowd.science](https://crowd.science/) is a crowd-funding platform for academic research which includes a host of examples of crowd-funded academic projects. Notable recent projects include the funding of [LSD brain imaging at Imperial College London](https://pharmaceutical-journal.com/article/news/scientists-use-crowdfunding-to-boost-research-into-lsd-effects-on-the-brain).